# create distance matrix using own calculation pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe composed of >50 dimensions.

Uusing euclidean distance, I can calculate the distance matrix:

```
import pandas as pd
df2=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4],'col2':[5,6,7,8]})
df2
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix
dm=pd.DataFrame(distance_matrix(df2.values, df2.values), index=df2.index, columns=df2.index)
dm
```

I want to put more emphasis on col1, so would like to use the formula:

```
sqrt(w1(x1-x2)^2 + w2(y1-y2)^2), w1=0.7, w2=0.3
```

reading through the documentation, I cannot find a way to implement this change. I am still relatively new to python, so wonder how I can implement this using pandas

is this possible to create?

Comment: How certain are you about the distance formula you have written? One glaring issue is that in the normal calculation your weights add up to 2, yet in this example your weights only add up to 1. So even if x1-x2 and y1-y2 have the same distance, your formula produces a totally different answer than the unweighted case.

Comment: Most references say that is the best way to calculate a weighted distance matrix, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917066/calculating-weighted-euclidean-distance-with-given-weights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) and supply your own metrics formula:

```
w = (0.7, 0.3)
pd.DataFrame(squareform(pdist(df2.values, lambda u, v: np.sqrt((w*(u-v)**2).sum()))), index=df2.index, columns=df2.index)
```

Comment: How would I add a specific test. ie. (np.where(u[3]==v[3],0,10).

Comment: not sure what you mean: in the example u and v have a length of 2.

Comment: if I were to add more columns, such that I wanted to check they were not the same prior to computation. Say I had col3  categorical, and want to compute the distance when they are different, ie col3 = ['a','a','b','c'], I would include test that u[3]!=v[3], and if so, then make a const value, such as with np.where(u[3]!=v[3],10,0)

Comment: why didn't you say that you made it a new question - it's much clearer now. see my [answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57874004/3944322)