# calculate distance matrix with mixed categorical and numerics

Tags: pandas, distance

I have a data frame with a mixture of numeric (15 fields) and categorical (5 fields) data.

I can create a complete distance matrix of the numeric fields following [create distance matrix using own calculation pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57729146/create-distance-matrix-using-own-calculation-pandas)

I want to include the categorical fields as well.

Using as template:

```
import scipy
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
df2=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4],'col2':[5,6,7,8],'col3':['cat','cat','dog','bird']})
df2
pd.DataFrame(squareform(pdist(df2.values, lambda u, v: np.sqrt((w*(u-v)**2).sum()))), index=df2.index, columns=df2.index)
```

in the squareform calculation, I would like to include the test `np.where(u[2]==v[2], 0, 10)` (as well as with the other categorical columns)

Hpw do I modify the lambda function to carry out this test as well

Here, the distance between [0,1]

```
= sqrt((2-1)^2 + (6-5)^2 + (cat - cat)^2)
= sqrt(1 + 1 + 0)
```

and the distance between [0,2]

```
= sqrt((3-1)^2 + (7-5)^2 + (dog - cat)^2)
= sqrt(4 + 4 + 100)
```

etc.

Can anyone suggest how I can implement this algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4],'col2':[5,6,7,8],'col3':['cat','cat','dog','bird']})

def fun(u,v):
    const = 0 if u[2] == v[2] else 10
    return np.sqrt((u[0]-v[0])**2 + (u[1]-v[1])**2 + const**2)

pd.DataFrame(squareform(pdist(df2.values, fun)), index=df2.index, columns=df2.index)
```

Result:

```
           0          1          2          3
0   0.000000   1.414214  10.392305  10.862780
1   1.414214   0.000000  10.099505  10.392305
2  10.392305  10.099505   0.000000  10.099505
3  10.862780  10.392305  10.099505   0.000000
```

Comment: I ran the code perfectly on my local machine, but when I transferred it to a different one, I got the error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'bird'    Any possible suggestions as to why?

Comment: At what line did you get the error? (at this one: `const = 0 if u[2] == v[2] else 10`?)

Comment: traceback errors show:     pd.DataFrame(squareform(pdist(df2.values, fun)), index=df2.index, columns=df2.index), then this comes down to an error in in pdist(X, metric, p, w, V, VI), specifically X = _convert_to_double(X). Next step down is error in _convert_to_double(X), specifically def _convert_to_double(X):
    142     if X.dtype != np.double:
--> 143         X = X.astype(np.double)
    144     if not X.flags.contiguous:
    145         X = X.copy()

Comment: as an aside, how do you highlight code in comments section. ctl + k does not work for me as it does in main section. Nor does putting 4 spaces before a code block

Comment: when I make a loop: for i in range(df2.shape[0]):
  for j in range(df2.shape[0]):
    if j<i: continue
    print(i, j, fun(df2.iloc[i,:],df2.iloc[j,:])) It works

Comment: very strange, maybe there's an older version of pandas on the other machine (you can check the version with `pd.__version__`), I tested the example and it works with 0.24.2 and 0.25.1. For code highlighting include your code in backticks (`), see also the help link that appears next to the comment field when you type in it.

Comment: tthanks. unfortunately same errors. will keep looking into it

Comment: Solved by matching scipy version, `import scipy; scipy.__version__`